# How to pass cjuidatepicker value to mysql createCommand query YII 1.1?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am using YII 1.1 for my project. I have a sql query to create a chart based on the date selected in cjuidatepicker.

Below is my code on the view

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'datefrom');
?>

                <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name' => 'datefrom',
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'datefrom',
    'id' => 'datefrom',
    // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
    'options' => array(
        'showAnim' => "slideDown",
        'changeMonth' => true,

        'numberOfMonths' => 1,
        //'showOn' => "button",
        //'buttonImageOnly' => false,
        'dateFormat' => "yy-mm-dd",
        'showButtonPanel' => true,
        'onClose' => 'js:function(selectedDate) { $("#date_from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate); }'
    )

));

?>

        <?php
echo $form->error($model, 'datetime');
?>

    </div>


           <div class="row">
        <?php
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'dateto');
?>

                <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name' => 'dateto',
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'dateto',
    'id' => 'dateto',

    // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
    'options' => array(
        'showAnim' => "slideDown",
        'changeMonth' => true,
        'numberOfMonths' => 1,
        'dateFormat' => "yy-mm-dd",
        'showButtonPanel' => true,
        'onClose' => 'js:function(selectedDate) { $("#date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate); }'
    )

));

?>
  </div>



<div class="row buttons">
        <?php
echo CHtml::link('Search', array(
    'commLog/statistic',
    'datefrom' => 'datefrom',
    'dateto' => 'dateto'
));
?>

    </div>
```

This is the code to generate the chart.

```
<?php
$xAxis =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT comm_mode.commType As Type FROM comm_log inner join comm_mode
ON comm_mode.id=comm_log.modeId where datetime between '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-08' group by commType")
            ->select('Type')


            ->queryColumn();

$data =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT  count(modeId)as Count FROM comm_log inner join comm_mode
ON comm_mode.id=comm_log.modeId where datetime between '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-08' group by commType")
            ->select('Count')

           ->queryColumn();   
     $data=array_map('intVal', $data);


        $this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
   'options' => array(
      'title' => array('text' => 'Total communication type chosen'),
      'xAxis' => array(
         'categories' => $xAxis,
      ),
      'yAxis' => array(
         'title' => array('text' => 'Communication chosen')
      ),
      'series' => array(
        array('type' => 'column','name'   => 'Quantity','data'   => $data,'shadow' => false,
                )

      )
   )
));

?>
```

I can generate the chart, but my problem is i have to pass the value that user selected to my sql query. Now i manually write the dates on the BETWEEN clause.
Can somebody help me how to pass the value to my query?
I have been stucked for a very long time. I am a beginner to YII. I need help.

Comment: Where you write the createcommand query? in controller or model?

Comment: @SrinivasaReddy, i write it in the view itself.